# Flutter : Video player in ListView.builder (using : Chewie)

Tags: flutter

I'm tyring to create a video player in ListView.builder. My videos are stored in Firestore. In ListView.builder when the videos are loaded there is no problem but whenever you scroll the page up & down i get an error in red box says:

A VideoPlayerController was used after being disposed.

I/flutter : Once you have called dispose() on a VideoPlayerController, it can no longer be used.

```
Widget _modeApp(){
  return new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: dataApp.length,
      itemBuilder: (context,i){
        String _path = dataApp[i].url;
        _controllers.add(new TextEditingController());
        _focusNode.add(new FocusNode());
        return new Card(
          child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                    width: 50.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black38),
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        image: new DecorationImage(image: new NetworkImage(dataApp[i].aurl))
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Text(dataApp[i].name,style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ],
              ),
                new Chewie(
                  VideoPlayerController.network(_path),
                    aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                    autoPlay: false,
                    looping: false,
              ),
                new Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0,top: 12.0),
                child: new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Icon(Icons.favorite_border,size: 27.0),
                    new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0)),
                    new Icon(Icons.chat_bubble_outline,size: 27.0),
                    new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0)),
                    new Icon(Icons.turned_in_not,size: 27.0),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
                new ListTile(
                title: new Text(dataApp[i].text,style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                subtitle:  new Text(dataApp[i].time),
              ),
                new ListTile(
                leading: new Container(
                  width: 50.0,
                  height: 50.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black38),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: widget.accountEmail == null
                        ? new DecorationImage(image: new NetworkImage("${widget.value.photoUrl}"))
                        : new DecorationImage(image: new NetworkImage("${widget.accountPhoto}")),
                  ),
                ),
                title: new EnsureVisibleWhenFocused(
                  focusNode: _focusNode[i],
                  child: new TextField(
                    focusNode: _focusNode[i],
                    controller: _controllers[i],
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                        color: Colors.black
                    ),
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: "Add a comment...",
                      hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                trailing: new IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.send, color: _controllers[i].text != "" ? Colors.blue : null), onPressed: _controllers[i].text != "" ? () => _showMessage(i) : null),
              ),
                new Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 13.0)),
            ],
          ),
        );}
      );
  }
```

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. enter your code in place of Lisrview.builder()

```
 Container(
            child: 
              SingleChildScrollView(
                    physics: new BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListView.separated(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          cacheExtent: 1000,
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          key: PageStorageKey(widget.position),
                          addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                          itemCount: itemList.isEmpty ? 0 : itemList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                              Container(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            height: 350.0,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
    
                            child: Container(
                                key: new PageStorageKey(
                                  "keydata$index",
                                ),
    
                                child: VideoWidget(
                                    play: true,
    
                                    url: itemList.elementAt(index),
                                )
                            ),
                          ),
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Divider();
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                 )
    
    class VideoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
    
      final bool play;
      final String url;
      
       const VideoWidget({Key key, @required this.url, @required this.play})
          : super(key: key);
          
            @override
      _VideoWidgetState createState() => _VideoWidgetState();
    }
    
    
    class _VideoWidgetState extends State<VideoWidget> {
      VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController ;
      Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
      
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        videoPlayerController = new VideoPlayerController.network(widget.url);
    
        _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = videoPlayerController.initialize().then((_) {
    //       Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
          setState(() {});
        });
    } // This closing tag was missing
        
         @override
      void dispose() {
         videoPlayerController.dispose();
    //    widget.videoPlayerController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
      
      
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      
      return FutureBuilder(
          future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return new Container(
    
                child: Card(
                key: new PageStorageKey(widget.url),
                  elevation: 5.0,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Chewie(
                          key: new PageStorageKey(widget.url),
                          controller: ChewieController(
                            videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
                            aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                            // Prepare the video to be played and display the first frame
                            autoInitialize: true,
                            looping: false,
                            autoPlay: false,
                            // Errors can occur for example when trying to play a video
                           // from a non-existent URL
                            errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
                              return Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  errorMessage,
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),  
                      ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            }
          },
        );
      }
     }
```

Comment: I like how the VideoWidget was abstracted into a class. :thumbsup:

Comment: what is widget.position? How can I use your code to create a facebook like news feed?

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't be creating the video player controllers in the build method. You want to create the controller outside of the build method so it doesn't keep getting recreated as you scroll.

Comment: but the issue is if i want to use videoplayer inside listview.builder then how can i do that because i dont know which index i have video its like instagram so when i start the videoplayer then the link must be provided, so how can i do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Please read about [Butter player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player).

I think this works for many possible application of video player in app.

Comment: *better player!!

Answer (score 3):

Play only one video at a time. To get currentIndex use [CarouselSlider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider). You will get index in onPageChanged parameter.

```
                        Container(
                            key: new PageStorageKey(
                              "keydata$index",
                            ),

                            child: VideoWidget(
                                play: index==currentIndex?true:false, //changed

                                url: itemList.elementAt(index),
                            )
                        ),
```

Comment: what if the there are two widgets on same page?